# Which properties does the polynomial ring $\mathcal{R}[X]$ inherit from the ring $\mathcal{R}$?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, big-list

I've learned that

- $\mathcal{R}$ is commutative → $\mathcal{R}[X]$ is commutative
- $\mathcal{R}$ has no zero divisors → $\mathcal{R}[X]$ has no zero divisors
- $\mathcal{R}$ is [unital](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/faq/) → $\mathcal{R}[X]$ is unital
- $\mathcal{R}$ is [factorial](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/properties/property/114/) → $\mathcal{R}[X]$ is factorial
- $\mathcal{R}$ is [Noetherian](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/properties/property/64/) → $\mathcal{R}[X]$ is Noetherian

Which other properties of a polynomial ring are inherited from its coefficient ring?

---

List of properties from the comments and answers below (without credits):

- $\mathcal{R}$ is [reduced](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/properties/property/10/) → $\mathcal{R}[X]$ is reduced
- $\mathcal{R}$ is [Abelian](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/properties/property/40/) → $\mathcal{R}[X]$ is Abelian
- $\mathcal{R}$ is [nonsingular](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/properties/property/73/) → $\mathcal{R}[X]$ is nonsingular
- $\mathcal{R}$ is [2-primal](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/properties/property/34/) → $\mathcal{R}[X]$ is 2-primal
- $\mathcal{R}$ is [Armendariz](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/properties/property/155/) → $\mathcal{R}[X]$ is Armendariz
- $\mathcal{R}$ has [characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)) $n$ → $\mathcal{R}[X]$ has characteristic $n$
- $\mathcal{R}$ has finite [Krull dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension) → $\mathcal{R}[X]$ has finite Krull dimension
- $\mathcal{R}$ has finite [global homological dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_dimension) → $\mathcal{R}[X]$ has finite global homological dimension

Comment: Well, any statement of the form "there exists an element such that..." will be inherited.

Comment: Is this obvious? Does the same hold for "there exists a subring such that..."?

Comment: Ah, and one "proper" example that should probably be added is "reduced".

Comment: Well, the "such that..." needs to not use any "for all..." to make sure it works.

Comment: Does the same hold for "there exists no element such that..."? (see zero divisors)

Comment: Not necessarily (since the added elements in the polynomial ring might satisfy the condition without any elements from the ring doing so).

Comment: [This is a version asked earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/446746/29335) although I think it was at a more restricted scope.

Answer (score 2):

A few examples:

"has finite Krull dimension"

"has finite global homological dimension"

"has characteristic $n$", for any $n$

Answer (score 2):

The current contents of DaRT yielded this list:

Properties passing to a polynomial ring of one variable:

nonsingular ring, 2-primal ring, reduced, Armendariz, Abelian, right Noetherian.

Properties *not* passing to the polynomial ring of one variable:

semicommutative, right principally injective, quasi Frobenius, right coherent, Boolean, periodic, Goldman domain, right Artinian, right principal ideal domain/ring, right self-injective, simple, von Neumann regular, right primitive, semisimple.

This is far from complete, of course, but I'm adding to it as I go.

I think I'm probably missing several of the nice commutative algebraic-geometry flavor rings from the first list, but I won't guess without confirmation.

Comment: What is an abelian ring?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft [all idempotents are central](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/properties/property/40/)

Comment: How would I have done the search for "properties passing to a polynomial ring of one variable" in DaRT? Is it predefined?

Comment: @HansStricker Unfortunately, there is not a search with that cross-section right now. One would have to individually visit the pages for each property and extract this information.  For me it's easier since I have admin tools that do it for me.  And as you can see, I don't have the information for most of the properties.