# A Simpler proof for a Principal Ideal Domain which is not a Euclidean Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains, unique-factorization-domains, euclidean-domain

It is well know that $\mathbb{Z} [(1 + \sqrt{-19})/2]$ is a PID which is not a Euclidean Domain. It is also accepted to be the simplest ring for which this is true.

I am wondering if anyone knows of a ring with this property that may be more complicated in its definition but the proof that it is a PID and not a ED is shorter. It is okay if this example uses ideas beyond basic ring theory.

Comment: Presumably, you mean $\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}{2}$?

Comment: Because I tend to understand things better that way. Also I am looking for a shorter proof which will take less time to write on my qualifying exam :)

Comment: Thanks Thomas Andrews I fixed it.

Comment: This [article](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.123.9.936) and this [MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405022/principal-ideal-domain-not-euclidean) might be helpful. (No doubt you are already aware of "simple" proofs for $\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{-19})/2]$ such as [this article](http://www.m-hikari.com/imf/imf-2013/29-32-2013/wongIMF29-32-2013.pdf) and its references, and of course Keith Conrad's always-great [exposition](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ringtheory/euclideanrk.pdf).)